# Setting Hour/Minute ranges with new Date function

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

The following function worked before I added the m variable into the if conditions. However, I noticed an error, when the time went from 11am to 12pm, the if else did not run the `noonTime` variable. I looked at my code and thought it had to do with minutes not being specified in the conditions. Initially my code was just like this: `var noonTime = (h >= 12 && h <= 17) ? true : false;`. I then changed it to this: `var noonTime = (h >= 12, m > 0 && h <= 17, m == 0) ? true : false;` to try and check for minutes in the condition.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with trying to check for the minutes in my conditions?

```js
var customerName = 'Bob';
function timeNow() {
  
        var d = new Date(),
        h = ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2),
        m = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

        // Checking time range
        var morningTime = (h >= 5 && h <= 12, m == 0) ? true : false;
        var noonTime    = (h >= 12, m > 0 && h <= 17, m == 0) ? true : false;
        var nightTime   = (h >= 17 && h <= 5)  ? true : false;
        var greeting = "";

        if (morningTime) {
            greeting = "Good Morning";
        } else if (noonTime) {
            greeting = "Good Afternoon";
        } else if (nightTime) {
            greeting = "Good Evening";
        }

        return greeting;
    }
   // var helloTime = timeNow();
    document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow() + ', ' + customerName + '!';
    //$('#dashboard-hello').html(helloTime + ', ' + customerName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-hello"></div>
```

Comment: Note that `(h >= 5 && h <= 12, m == 0) ? true : false;` is equivalent to just `(h >= 5 && h <= 12, m == 0);`. There's no need for the ternary.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks! Do you know how I could account for the minutes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could try giving us some more exact times and what problems you're running into with them.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am trying to account for hours and minutes. My prior code was just hours. So, for instance if it is 12:00pm, it will still say morning, but then when it turns 12:01, it will say the noon message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to combine your hour and minute comparisons. Using parentheses for these groupings make them easier to read. Then you just use the ranges you want.

```js
function getGreeting(d) {
  h = d.getHours(), // There's no reason to format these as
    m = d.getMinutes(); // strings, since you're comparing to numbers

  // Checking time range
  var morningTime = ((h >= 5 && h < 12) || (h === 12 && m == 0));
  var noonTime = ((h === 12 && m > 0) || (h > 12 && h < 17) || (h === 17 && m === 0));
  var nightTime = (h >= 17 || h <= 5)
  var greeting = "";

  if (morningTime) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
  } else if (noonTime) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
  } else if (nightTime) {
    greeting = "Good Evening";
  }

  return greeting;
}

console.log("now: " + getGreeting(new Date()));
console.log("5 am: " + getGreeting(new Date(1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0)));
console.log("12:00pm: " + getGreeting(new Date(1, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0)));
console.log("12:01pm: " + getGreeting(new Date(1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 0)));
console.log("5:00pm: " + getGreeting(new Date(1, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0)));
console.log("5:01pm: " + getGreeting(new Date(1, 1, 1, 17, 1, 0)));
console.log("12:00am: " + getGreeting(new Date(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)));
```

I've made the date an argument to a function for testing purposes. To return it, just remove `d` and put your first line of code back in.

Comment: Gotcha! Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The comma operator will evaluate each of the operands but only return the value of the last one. In this case you may be better off using some more AND/OR operators to better evaluate what you're trying to do.

I'm actually not entirely sure what you're trying to do but maybe you want:

```
var morningTime = ((h >= 5 && h <= 12) && m == 0) ? true : false;
var noonTime    = ((h >= 12 && m > 0) && (h <= 17 && m == 0)) ? true : false;
```

But maybe you could simplify the whole code segment even more like this...

```
if (h > 5 && h <= 12) {
  return "Good Morning";
}
else if (h > 12 && h <= 17)
  return "Good Afternoon";
}
else if (h > 17 && h <= 5)
  return "Good Evening";
}
```

Comment: What could I use alternatively?